# Exec tag being used for Find questions

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Several users are associating the [exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exec) tag (244 questions) with Find's `-exec` option. [Find && Exec](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bexec%5D+and+%5Bfind%5D) tagged questions amounts to almost the half of that value (105 questions). The tag's description, however, does not include that meaning:

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image, retaining the pid and pipes of the old process. This tag is also used for the shell built-in which can be used to replace the current shell with a program or various redirection-related stuff.

Should we remove the tag where its usage is inappropriate or would it be preferable to include that meaning to the tag?

Comment: IMO, any question relating to `-exec` should be tagged with [tag:find], not [tag:exec]. It would be appropriate to correct questions with the wrong sets of tags. If this is best done in bulk or a bit every now and again, I don't know.

Comment: The only thing I'm concerned about with regards to bulk edits is that it pushes new questions off the front page if too many are done at once.

Comment: `-exec`  is the predicate that tells `find` to use those `exec*()`  system calls (in addition to `fork()` and `wait*()` of course), so it's not completely irrelevant. The shell's `exec` is more a *no-fork* command, so it's less relevant to `exec*()` than `find`'s `-exec` I'd say.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Usually, when someone has an issue using `-exec` with `find`, it is a `find` issue (syntax, how to find the wanted things, how to loop over results, etc.), not an `exec*()` issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda, or it's an issue about executing things with `find`. If the exec tag is already used for the `exec` special builtin of shell and for the `exec*()` system calls, we might as well use it for anything that's named `exec`. I won't argue much more about it, regardless of what it's used for I doubt it will be useful for anything anyway.

Comment: Rename exec to something more specific, like exec-syscall or something and done.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas in that case, the exec tag would refer to two things: a find predicate and a system call. Tags are supposed to mean exactly one thing. If we need a tag for the system call, it has to be its own tag. Also, that would mean that any command that executes the exec syscall should use the tag, which would dilute its usefulness.

Comment: It makes very little sense to have *any* tag that refers to an option.  All tags for commands should be for the command itself.

Comment: In any case, there's no `exec()` system call. There are some `execve()`, `execv()`, `execveat()` , `fexecve()` and there are some standard C API functions around those like `execl()`, `execvp()`... And some languages including `perl`/`python` have some `exec` function around those. shells' whole raison d'être is to expose that system call to the user. Its own `exec` builtin is to not do it in a child process (with differences in behaviour between implementation when the command is builtin or a function). `find`'s `-exec` is also a wrapper around those (though in a child process).

Comment: @Chenmunka, `-exec` is not an option of `find`, it's a predicate. The options are `-H` and `-L` (some implementations have more). `-exec`  is an *action predicate* in the `find` language like `exec` is an action function in the `perl` language. They are both about executing commands. What we need here is drawing the line as to what `exec` is meant to be used for. My personal line is "I don't care much, my only usage of tags is for the watch and ignore tag feature, and I can't see how that tag can be useful to anything".

Answer (score 2):

To my mind, the `find` tag should be for questions with regard to the `find` command and its invocations (including the `-exec` and `-execdir` arguments), uses, permutations, idiosyncracies, and foibles.

Similarly, the `exec` tag (as currently defined) should be for questions specifically about the system call, its uses, invocations, permutations, and foibles.

If we expand the scope of the tag meant for discussing the `exec()` system call to include things which just happen to as a consequence of their use *invoke* the system call, then tagging the system call itself is devoid of all meaning.

As such, I would be inclined to remove the `exec` tags from such questions where it is present, and add the `find` tag where it is absent.

Comment: But most of the usages of the `exec` tag ATM the moment are for that `find -exec` or the `exec` builtin of some shells, not the `execve()` system call or the family of `exec*()` C library functions (there are some, but they are a minority). Should we retag them and update the tag definition to remove the reference to the shell builtin? Or should we on the other hand extend it to the `exec` functions of languages other than C (perl, ruby, python, sh, csh, ... find)?

Comment: That is a good question, but I believe it to be out of scope of the question at hand ("Is `exec` a relevant tag for `find` questions?").

Comment: But your answer currently contradicts the tag definition, and suggests it should be changed to exclude using that tag for the `exec` sh builtin.

Comment: I don't see how the answer ("remove the `exec` tag from questions about `find` where it is present, and add the `find` tag where it is absent) contradicts the definition of the `exec` tag.  Whether the definition of the `exec` tag should be modified or whether a `bash-exec` tag should be created is, again, an whole other question.

Comment: You're saying *should be for questions specifically about the system call, its uses...*, the current tag definition says: *This tag is also used for the shell built-in which can be used to replace the current shell with a program or various redirection-related stuff*. `exec 2>&1` is a wrapper around the `dup2()` system call, not the  `execve()` system call (no Unix-lie system has a `exec()` system call btw AFAIK).